# How do I emulate a slow network connection in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, ip

In some unix flavours you can emulate a slow network connection to, say 4KB/s using

```
sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 4KByte/s
sudo ipfw add 100 pipe 1 tcp from any to me 80
```

Is there an equivalent in Windows?

Comment: google traffic shaper: http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html

Comment: @pivotnig is there anything for the windows-7 the link you provided is for the window-xp

Comment: you're welcome... what else did you want, hardware?

Comment: @pivotnig sir,its not about the software its about how to do this by coding if you tell me how to do this i appreciate your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- run
- gpedit.msc
- Computer Configuration
- Administrative Templates
- Network
- QOS Package Scheduler
- Limit Reservable Bandwidth
- Settings

then you will find "bandwidth percentage limiter", set it and click "OK."

Comment: But ... (gpedit.msc) "The Local Group Policy Editor feature is not included in the Windows 7 Starter, Home Basic, and Home Premium editions"